# What is the difference between lastModified and lastUpdated in the info of an artifact in Artifactory

Tags: artifactory

When I list the storage info of an artifact in Artifactory I have two fields: lastModified and lastUpdated.
What is the difference between the two?

I make an api rest call with /api/storage/... where I ge the artifact information like:

{
"repo": "docker-prod-local2",
"path": "/xxx/services/20210223-164230/manifest.json",
"created": "2021-02-24T09:57:10.253+01:00",
"createdBy": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
"**lastModified**": "2021-02-24T09:57:10.041+01:00",
"modifiedBy": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"**lastUpdated**": "2021-02-24T09:57:10.253+01:00",
"downloadUri": "http://xxxxxxxxxx/artifactory/docker-prod-local2/xxx/services/20210223-164230/manifest.json",
"mimeType": "application/json",
"size": "9555",
"checksums": {
"sha1": "05383fb636c07e70eb9be723822b6d7895d36c23",
"md5": "30406da1ef0a4e21d35d200ace828cb5",
"sha256": "820ee4f78dbf17265a49f6ee59256575bb9af68ee41f333f101379c0220e7522"
},
"originalChecksums": {
"sha256": "820ee4f78dbf17265a49f6ee59256575bb9af68ee41f333f101379c0220e7522"
},
"uri": "http://xxxxxxxxxx/artifactory/api/storage/docker-prod-local2/xxx/services/20210223-164230/manifest.json"
}

Answer (score 0):

**lastModified** - This attribute would indicate the timestamp from the File system when the item was last modified.

**lastUpdated** - This would indicate the latest time of upload of the artifact to that particular repository.